# Having some page with roman number before beginning of document

Tags: page-numbering

I want to have a document. Before its *Table of Content* I would like to have some pages with roman page numbers for (Acknowledgments and etc.)

Could you please say me how can I do that for this example?

```
\documentclass[12pt,ngerman,openany]{report}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\selectlanguage{ngerman}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{page}{4}
\tableofcontents 
\chapter{Einleitung}
\section{Motivation}
Ukraine from 2006-2009 and is currently the vice president for Middle East and Africa at the United States Institute of Peace. 
Dr. George Lopez, a sanctions expert, is the vice president of the Academy for International Conflict Management and Peacebuilding at USIP. The views expressed here are their own.
(CNN) -- With their invasion of Crimea and their support for the violent -- and now murderous -- pro-Russian separatists in eastern Ukraine, the Russian government has grossly and blatantly violated international law, international treaties and international norms that have underpinned post-World War II and post- Cold War Europe.
In response, the United States quickly imposed travel bans and asset freezes on Russians and Ukrainian separatists; the European Union followed sui
\section{Ziel}

Europe does more trade with Russian firms, depends on Russian natural gas and sells into Russian markets.
They have tried to look away from the Russian-sponsored turmoil in Ukraine, hoping their economic interests can be spared.
That is no longer a viable policy option. If Russia is to be moved to change course, coordinated intensification is needed.
France has been the prime example of European protectionism. The Russians are set to purchase two helicopter aircraft carriers from the French for about 1.6 billion.
President Francois Hollande said on Monday France will go ahead with the sale of the first of these two ships, although he said the delivery of the second carrier would depend on Moscow's attitude. bla
\chapter{Stand der Technik zur Mustererkennung}
\section{Die Zeitreihen}
The international community united to impose harsh economic sanctions on Iranian oil exports, banking system and economic activity. As a result, the Iranians are now negotiating seriously in an attempt to lift these sanctions in return for assurances that their nuclear program is entirely peaceful.
Unified sanctions by the U.S. and Europe can give Putin two choices: double down on his support for the separatists in eastern Ukraine and face yet more sanctions and possible full scale isolation from the international community; or disavow these separatists and seal the Russian border so that further weapons, trainers, finance, security forces and volunteers can no longer flow into Ukraine.
But the latter, preferred choice will not come unless the European leaders act now to implement recent measures they have authorized and move to the 'Phase 3' sanctions they have available to them. bla
\subsection{Beschreibung}
won't have to wait long -- two will soon be built in China.
The world's tallest towers, futuristic pink spires that "breath life" into the environment, are due to begin construction within two years.
The ambitious Phoenix towers were designed by London-based architects Chetwoods and will claim the tallest building title from Dubai's Burj Khalifa.
And the design goes one step further: The towers will be one of the world's most environmentally-friendly buildings.
Stretching up more than a kilometer into the skies above Wuhan, the capital of China's Hubei province, the Phoenix project aims to clean the air and water from its surrounding areas. It's expected to become a tourist attraction for both Chinese and international travelers. bla
\subsection{Erklärung}

But perhaps the most controversial architectural feature are the huge celestial orbs strung between the two towers, housing restaurants and viewing platforms. The designs are unusual, the "sort of idea that China embraces, that perhaps somewhere else in the world they think you're going too far there," Chetwood said.
The towers will glow in vibrant pink, as a nod to the fuchsia flower. While architects often pivot to monochromatic colors, Chetwood wanted to mix it up with color. Also, he adds, "I hold my hands up and say I actually like the color and thought it would look stunning." bla

\subsection{Vorhersage}
 While Ukraine's fight for freedom gets bloodier by the day and Russia faces the West's cold shoulder, in the elegant surroundings of London's Somerset House, one oligarch is using art to get his message across.
"This work is called 'Widows,' for one simple reason," says Andrei Filatov as he points towards a picture of five elderly ladies looking forlorn. "Because instead of an icon [on the wall] there is Karl Marx."
And in cottages where the father of socialism has taken the Holy Mother's place, he explains, "this tells us the women depicted have probably lost their husbands in the war." bla
\subsection{Kontrolle}
And like many practical business people with a sizeable stake in this complex region, Filatov leaves the artwork to make the bold political statements, saying only he considers sanctions imposed by the EU and the U.S., "a big mistake."
According to Filatov, "the sooner there is an understanding by the European countries and the U.S., the faster there will be logical, sensible and constructive relations."
Putting on a large Russian art show in London at a time of heightened animosity towards his country is an ambitious project. Even talking about art, at a time of deadly skirmishes in Ukraine, may seem flippant but Filatov does have another motive for wanting to host the show: to cater for the British capital's sizeable Russian expat population.
"Walking around here I discovered there is not one large collection of Russian art," he says. bla
\section{Feature Extraktion}
And like many practical business people with a sizeable stake in this complex region, Filatov leaves the artwork to make the bold political statements, saying only he considers sanctions imposed by the EU and the U.S., "a big mistake."
According to Filatov, "the sooner there is an understanding by the European countries and the U.S., the faster there will be logical, sensible and constructive relations."
Putting on a large Russian art show in London at a time of heightened animosity towards his country is an ambitious project. Even talking about art, at a time of deadly skirmishes in Ukraine, may seem flippant but Filatov does have another motive for wanting to host the show: to cater for the British capital's sizeable Russian expat population.
"Walking around here I discovered there is not one large collection of Russian art," he says. bla
\subsection{Autokorrelation}
\subsection{Was ist Autokorrelation?}
And like many practical business people with a sizeable stake in this complex region, Filatov leaves the artwork to make the bold political statements, saying only he considers sanctions imposed by the EU and the U.S., "a big mistake."
According to Filatov, "the sooner there is an understanding by the European countries and the U.S., the faster there will be logical, sensible and constructive relations."
Putting on a large Russian art show in London at a time of heightened animosity towards his country is an ambitious project. Even talking about art, at a time of deadly skirmishes in Ukraine, may seem flippant but Filatov does have another motive for wanting to host the show: to cater for the British capital's sizeable Russian expat population.
"Walking around here I discovered there is not one large collection of Russian art," he says. bla


\subsection{Autokorrelation und Zeitreihen}
And like many practical business people with a sizeable stake in this complex region, Filatov leaves the artwork to make the bold political statements, saying only he considers sanctions imposed by the EU and the U.S., "a big mistake."
According to Filatov, "the sooner there is an understanding by the European countries and the U.S., the faster there will be logical, sensible and constructive relations."
Putting on a large Russian art show in London at a time of heightened animosity towards his country is an ambitious project. Even talking about art, at a time of deadly skirmishes in Ukraine, may seem flippant but Filatov does have another motive for wanting to host the show: to cater for the British capital's sizeable Russian expat population.
"Walking around here I discovered there is not one large collection of Russian art," he says. bla

\subsubsection{Zeitreihe-Diagramm}

And like many practical business people with a sizeable stake in this complex region, Filatov leaves the artwork to make the bold political statements, saying only he considers sanctions imposed by the EU and the U.S., "a big mistake."
According to Filatov, "the sooner there is an understanding by the European countries and the U.S., the faster there will be logical, sensible and constructive relations."
Putting on a large Russian art show in London at a time of heightened animosity towards his country is an ambitious project. Even talking about art, at a time of deadly skirmishes in Ukraine, may seem flippant but Filatov does have another motive for wanting to host the show: to cater for the British capital's sizeable Russian expat population.
"Walking around here I discovered there is not one large collection of Russian art," he says. bla
\subsubsection{Lagged Streudiagramm}
And like many practical business people with a sizeable stake in this complex region, Filatov leaves the artwork to make the bold political statements, saying only he considers sanctions imposed by the EU and the U.S., "a big mistake."
According to Filatov, "the sooner there is an understanding by the European countries and the U.S., the faster there will be logical, sensible and constructive relations."
Putting on a large Russian art show in London at a time of heightened animosity towards his country is an ambitious project. Even talking about art, at a time of deadly skirmishes in Ukraine, may seem flippant but Filatov does have another motive for wanting to host the show: to cater for the British capital's sizeable Russian expat population.
"Walking around here I discovered there is not one large collection of Russian art," he says. bla

\subsubsection{Autocorrelation-Function (Korrelogramm)}
And like many practical business people with a sizeable stake in this complex region, Filatov leaves the artwork to make the bold political statements, saying only he considers sanctions imposed by the EU and the U.S., "a big mistake."
According to Filatov, "the sooner there is an understanding by the European countries and the U.S., the faster there will be logical, sensible and constructive relations."
Putting on a large Russian art show in London at a time of heightened animosity towards his country is an ambitious project. Even talking about art, at a time of deadly skirmishes in Ukraine, may seem flippant but Filatov does have another motive for wanting to host the show: to cater for the British capital's sizeable Russian expat population.
"Walking around here I discovered there is not one large collection of Russian art," he says. bla
\subsection{Spektralanalyse}
\subsection{Was ist Spektral-Analyse}
And like many practical business people with a sizeable stake in this complex region, Filatov leaves the artwork to make the bold political statements, saying only he considers sanctions imposed by the EU and the U.S., "a big mistake."
According to Filatov, "the sooner there is an understanding by the European countries and the U.S., the faster there will be logical, sensible and constructive relations."
Putting on a large Russian art show in London at a time of heightened animosity towards his country is an ambitious project. Even talking about art, at a time of deadly skirmishes in Ukraine, may seem flippant but Filatov does have another motive for wanting to host the show: to cater for the British capital's sizeable Russian expat population.
"Walking around here I discovered there is not one large collection of Russian art," he says. bla
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\frontmatter`?

Comment: @Johannes_B -- `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter` are the "logical" answer, but unfortunately, they aren't provided in the `report` class, only for `book`.

Comment: So what should your page number sequence look like: i, ii, iii, 4, 5, 6, ...?

Comment: @Werner yes exactly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use specially-placed commands to switch between the page number representation:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,ngerman,openany]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\selectlanguage{ngerman}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}% Pages will be numbered i, ii, iii, iv, v, vi, ...
Something on page i
\clearpage
Something on page ii
\clearpage
Something on page iii
\clearpage

\renewcommand{\thepage}{\arabic{page}}% Pages will be numbered 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, ...
\tableofcontents 
\chapter{Einleitung}
\section{Motivation}
Ukraine from 2006-2009 and is currently the vice president for Middle East and Africa at the United States Institute of Peace. 
%...
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 `\renewcommand{\thepage}{}` will not reset the number but resume. So you have to say `4,...` rather than `1,...` in the code comment.